# jQuery Dialog firing before Update Panel has had a chance to update itself

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, jquery-ui-dialog

Ive got a ASP.NET webforms page with an empty update panel and a button.

The button's click event has a javascript event listener to open the jQuery `dialog`, and also make a postback to populate the update panel's contents.

Both of these work-ish, in that the update panel does indeed populate with content, and the jquery `dialog` also opens, however, due to the way the the jQuery `dialog` works, I believe it 'copies' the contents of the update panel before it has had a chance to update, so ends up showing the user an empty `dialog`.

Answer (score 0):

If the update is done by `$.ajax()` then call the `jQuery dialog open()` inside the `complete: function(){}` block of the ajax request. Or you can use a `setTimeout()` for the pop-up dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Try endRequest event to open the jquery dialog:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

function EndRequestHandler(sender,args) {
    //this fires when the partial postback is finished
    // open the dialog here
});
```

More on [endRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).